# SQL group by multiple columns

Tags: group-by

Say I have the following table, where a group of 3 people from 3 locations work together on a project that is scored.

```
|   | Score | Possible_Score | Loc_A | Loc_B | Loc_C |
|---|-------|----------------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1 | 80    | 100            | LA    | LA    | Bos   |
| 2 | 90    | 100            | LA    | Bos   | NYC   |
| 3 | 70    | 100            | NYC   | NYC   | LA    |
```

I want to get overall scores by location, where each project that has at least 1 person from that location contributes to the location's score. So, in this case, I'd want an output like:

```
|   | Location | Score | Poss_Score |
|---|----------|-------|------------|
| 1 | Bos      | 170   | 200        |
| 2 | LA       | 240   | 300        |
| 3 | NYC      | 160   | 200        |
```

How can I do this in SQL? I know how to group by location, but I don't know how to group by location when it can be from any of 3 columns. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

A solution that work in most DBMS is to use a union:

```
 select loc_a as location, Score, Possible_Score from T
 union all
 select loc_b as location, Score, Possible_Score from T
 union all
 select loc_c as location, Score, Possible_Score from T
```

Now you can sum that up as:

```
select location, sum(score), sum(possible_score)
from (
     select loc_a as location, Score, Possible_Score from T
     union all
     select loc_b as location, Score, Possible_Score from T
     union all
     select loc_c as location, Score, Possible_Score from T
) as TT
group by location;
```

If your DBMS supports LATERAL JOIN you can do something like:

```
select x.location, sum(x.score), sum(x.possible_score)
from T
cross join lateral (
    values (T.loc_a, T.score, T.possible_score)
         , (T.loc_b, T.score, T.possible_score)
         , (T.loc_c, T.score, T.possible_score)
) X (location, score, possible_score)
group by x.location;
```

LATERAL makes it possible to reference T in X, so we can use X to normalize location.